# How to turn specific shopify collection as a homepage?

Tags: collections, shopify

[Website Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAdp.png)

Is there any way I can turn my collection page into a home page? I already search but I can't find any solution for this.

Comment: use an alternative layout and copy all the code to this layout and assign the layout to `index.liquid`, needs some coding skills to adjust and works well if there are sections that are used then you might need to duplicate them if you want to separate the content on both pages.

Comment: I'm gonna try this, hope it works thanks @Onkar